# снова пунктуация

Tags: пунктуация

Описанное А. Н. Леонтьевым «вычерпывание» субъективного образа из мира  Е. Ю. Артемьева (Артемьева, 1999) интерпретирует как впервые предложенную модель слияния в одном психическом акте процесса, образа и реальности. Просто очень хочется поставить запятую после "мира", чтобы как-то отделить эти конструкты. А как правильно?

Answer (score 1):

Хочется. Оснований нет. Только пресловутая интонационная запятая, а это вещь обоюдоострая. Или менять порядок слов, но тогда персоны окажутся далеко по тексту от своих творений, что будет ошибкой уже стилистической.

Тут контекст нужен.

Вот если так...

***«Вычерпывание» субъективного образа из мира, описанное А. Н. Леонтьевым, Е. Ю. Артемьева (Артемьева, 1999) интерпретирует как впервые предложенную модель слияния в одном психическом акте процесса, образа и реальности.***

Это на случай, если раньше про "вычерпывание" не говорилось.

А если говорилось, то еще проще.

***Такое, описанное А. Н. Леонтьевым «Вычерпывание» субъективного образа из мира, Е. Ю. Артемьева (Артемьева, 1999) интерпретирует как впервые предложенную модель слияния в одном психическом акте процесса, образа и реальности.***

Называется: обманули пунктуацию. Влепили запятую по другим мотивам.

*Откуда у вас столько вопросов? ))) Мне пора вахту сдавать. Или деньги с Вас брать)))*

Answer (score 1):

Формально запятая не требуется, но при чтении теряется нужная в этом месте речевая пауза и возникает недоразумение: мир некоего Артемьева, интерпретируемый "вычерпыванием". Поэтому, возможно, лучше изменить порядок слов. Если здесь дословное цитирование второго автора, могут понадобиться кавычки.

«Вычерпывание» субъективного образа из мира, описанное А. Н. Леонтьевым, Е. Ю. Артемьева интерпретирует как впервые предложенную модель слияния в одном психическом акте процесса, образа и реальности (Артемьева, 1999).

То, что описано А. Н. Леонтьевым как «вычерпывание» субъективного образа из мира, Е. Ю. Артемьева интерпретирует как впервые предложенную модель слияния в одном психическом акте процесса, образа и реальности (Артемьева, 1999).

Answer (score 1):

Предложу ещё вариант. Описанное А. Н. Леонтьевым «вычерпывание» субъективного образа из мира интерпретируется Е. Ю. Артемьевой (Артемьева, 1999)  как впервые предложенная модель слияния в одном психическом акте процесса, образа и реальности.

Answer (score 1):

Можно поставить, иначе фраза плохо воспринимается.

Comment: Подробнее пишите.

Answer (score 0):

Ох уж этот "деревянный" язык научных работ и монографий! Сколько с ним ранее возиться пришлось... )) По сути вопроса. "Сносим" все лишнее. В сухом остатке имеем:

"Описанное «вычерпывание» Е. Ю. Артемьева интерпретирует как модель слияния в одном психическом акте процесса, образа и реальности". И где тут ставить запятую?

Для себя лично давным-давно сделал вывод: не стоит относиться к "научному" русскому точно так же, как к литературному. В нем "удобочитаемость" всегда приносится в жертву предельной насыщенности терминами и максимальной точности...

Comment: Вы вредные советы даете, гр. Толстый Тролль. Здесь ценят правописание, а не фантазии.

Comment: Переходите на личности, толстокожий и хамоватый вы наш? )) Ай-я-яй! Фантазии, похоже, у вас - насчет того, кто здесь типа самый главный. ))